# Testing a Laravel package

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

So, I'm writing a basic Laravel package and I seem to have stumbled upon yet another problem, this time with testing.

The package in development is currently in a `packages` folder in the root of the project. I have modified the `composer.json` file of the package to include the dependencies I need

```
"require-dev": {
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
    "laravel/laravel": "dev-develop"
}
```

However , whenever I try running `phpunit tests` in the package folder (which contains a folder named `tests` along with a sample test), I get the following error:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase' not found in /workspace/laravel/packages/sample/http-request/tests/HttpRequestTest.php on line 8

The test file is just the auto-generated stub:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class HttpRequestTest extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

Any idea why this isn't working? The app tests run without a hitch, but the app itself doesn't have dependencies other than what's in the box.

**SOLUTION**

Managed to make it work independently by extending the PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase:

```
class HttpRequestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
```

However , running it like:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit packages/yourname/package-name/
```

Works as well, so I picked it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for wanting to add a solution here. In future, please add that as an answer below the question - we like a clean separation between Q&A here. Cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me:

```
class HttpRequestTest extends TestCase
```

And running test with:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit packages/yourname/package-name/
```

Comment: Nope, still doesn't find anything :( Again, it's in a packages/... folder , which in turn has it's own vendor folder with dev dependencies, not in the root of the app, where it works for me as well

Comment: I've updated post, I'm running package tests like this and it works.

Comment: Ah great. It works. However it uses the application's dependencies , which wouldn't be feasible with say TravisCI. I've found another way - I just use PHPUnit's bundled TestCase.

Comment: Thanks, this one helps me.

Answer (score 1):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP as an answer)*.

Managed to make it work independently by extending the PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase:

```
class HttpRequestTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
```

However , running it like:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit packages/yourname/package-name/
```

Works as well, so I picked it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows environments you need to use backslashes!

`vendor\bin\phpunit packages\yourname\package-name`

Answer (score 0):

- Create a directory named `tests` in your root of the package and write various test classes inside it. You can have all functioning of your package inside various methods in a single class or you can use multiple classes.
- Move to your project's root and run following commands,

  `vendor/bin/phpunit packages/YOUR_DIRECTORY_NAME/PACKAGE_NAME`
- Wait a little and you will get the response for your test cases. No. of positive and negative tests will be shown.